# placeholder string partially visible in angular js

Tags: ajax, angularjs

My placeholder string is partially visible in angular js.

```
var select2BaseOpts = {
    openOnEnter: true,
    allowClear: true,
    closeOnSelect: false,
    dropdownAutoWidth: true,
    width: '100%'
};
```

If I dont include

```
dropdownAutoWidth: true,
width: '100%'
```

then the dropdown list width goes out of the current window but placeholder string is fully visible. If I include them, then dropdown list width is proper but placeholder string in not completely visible.

Comment: you should elaborate more.

Comment: once I click on the input box, then only the placeholder string is visible completely.

Comment: how can we make the width of placeholder same as that of input box ?